# Oracle Service Bus DB Adapter

Tags: web-services

I am trying to use Oracle Service Bus DB Adapter to create a REST based service. There are four paramters that get passed in the query out of which at any time only 2 are passed. For example:

http://www.example.com/findPerson/personId=&birthDt=&ss=&lastname=

birthDt is always passed, but only 1 of the other 3 are passed. The other parameters are empty.

For me to do a database lookup, all I need is birthDt and 1 of the other 3 passed.

Is there a way in OSB to do a conditional select based on what is passed in? Do I do a Select or "Query By Example" or "Invoke a stored procedure" that returns what I need?

In the response to the REST service call, I need to return several elements in an XML format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a stored procedure in the backend which has all the input parameters as input (and 3 of them have 'default null')

create or replace procedure my_procedure
  (p_parm1 in varchar2 default null, etc ..

and in the stored procedure you check what parameters are filled to construct your select statement.
In the xquery on the osb you will need to check which parameters from your rest call are filled in, to map these on the optional parameters of your stored procedure call.

Or you can use the 'select statement' option in the db adapter and use some construction like this :

select *
from my_table
where kolom1 = :p_name or :p_name is null

Now you can expand the whole query based on the values of your input parameters

Also for this case you need an xquery in the osb which will 'map' your rest parameters to the select statement parameters.
Easiest way is i think to just pass on the whole query-parameter string into your xquery and use substring/substring-after etc to get the different parameters out of it together with their values and map these values to the input xml payload of your db adapter call.

Comment: Thanks Eric. This helps. I will try both options. As part of the result, I would need to return a ton of information. Hopefully should be able to do that in both cases.